# Single program run a year on 8-cpus machine

Tags: cpu

Suppose I have a 8-CPU machine, which run a single process and one thread program

```
  while True: report time every hour.
```

The program run one year alive.

During the passed whole year, did  the program run solely on one core, or might visit every core?

Comment: What language is this program being run in?

Comment: @Jesse_b almost certainly irrelevant since almost every language implements threads on top of native operating system threads.  The code in the question can be run as psudo code.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: Probably but I'm not familiar with all programming languages and I wouldn't doubt if some of them automatically implement multithreading.  Of course OP said it would be a one thread program so is that actually specified in the program or assumed?

Comment: @Jesse_b I'm familiar with a lot of languages and none of the ones I know do. Further its very unlikely that they would go through the pain of implementing their own time slicer & stack management when it would screw with their ability to run different threads on different CPUs.  There is a concept of "tasks" in C# and Python that can mess with the concept of threads a little, but they have to be used explicitly in the language and are nothing like threads when you understand them.

Comment: I want to assure the possibility of the kernel to arrange tasks to CPU so if any language run a program on various cores, I got the answer. @Jesse_b

Answer (score 2):

The Linux scheduler will try to run the program always on the same CPU, but that is not guaranteed. Cf. [CPU affinity](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6799).

Comment: ty, I got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the scheduler move a process around, too reduce local warming effects (this happens in time of order a second). It is also free to move it for any other reason, however it will try to keep it on the same core, as this will use the same cache, and prevent a cache flush.

In a year there will be so many opportunities for the core/cpu to change that I would say that the probability is close enough to 100% that makes no difference.

You can restrict the cpu/core that a process runs on. If you do this then it is guaranteed.